Stripe subscription - PayPal payments method does work on live mode
I'm trying to implement paypal payment method with subscription mode on stripe it works fine on test mode but on live it doesn't.
I activated paypal wallet in my stripe dashboard like the error stated. It works on test mode but it doesn't in live mode.
This is the client side and server side code:
Server Side
exports.createCheckoutSession = async function (req, res) {
  const data = req.body;
  const accountId = data.accountId;
  const plan = data.plan;
  const accountData = await account.get(accountId);
  utils.assert(accountData, "No account with that ID", null, "NO-ACCOUNT");
  
  // Create new Checkout Session for the order
  try {
   // Create customer
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    email: accountData.email,
  });
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    mode: "subscription",
    payment_method_types: ["paypal"],
    line_items: [{ price: plan, quantity: 1 }],
    customer:id,
    success_url: `${domain}/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancel_url: `${domain}/cancel`,
    automatic_tax: { enabled: true },
    customer_update: {
      address: 'auto',
    },
  });

    res.json({url: session.url});
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400);
    return res.send({
      error: {
        message: e.message,
      },
    });
  }
};


exports.retreiveCheckoutSession = async (req, res) => {
  const { sessionId } = req.query;

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(sessionId);

  res.send(session);
};

exports.saveSessiondata = async function (req, res) {
  const data = req.body;
  const accountId = data.accountId;
  const stripeData = data.stripeData;
  
  let subscription;
  let plan

  if (stripeData.subscription) {
    subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create(stripeData.subscription);
    }}


It looks like you just need to enable PayPal recurring payments on your account. These aren't enabled by default, so just follow the instructions here.
